# How to test sending eth to function using ethers.js?

Tags: testing, ethers.js, hardhat, transfer

I'm net to eth dev and trying to test sending eth while assigning a value to `betOnTeam` function:

```php
    function betOnTeam(uint8 _team) public payable {
       // assign usre to _team and add betting value to totalBetsOne 
    }

    function AmountOne() public view returns (uint256) {
        return totalBetsOne;
    }
```

The test that I've written in hardhat:

```js
    const { expect } = require("chai");
    const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
    
 
    let betting;
    let owner;
    let addr1;
    let addr2;
    let addrs;
    
    beforeEach(async function () {
      Betting = await ethers.getContractFactory("Betting");
      [owner, addr1, addr2, ...addrs] = await ethers.getSigners();
      betting = await Betting.deploy();
    });
    
    describe("Deployment", function () {
      it("Should set the right owner", async function () {
        expect(await betting.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
      });
      it("Initial bet values should be zero", async function () {
       // const ownerBalance = await betting.balanceOf(owner.address);
        expect(await betting.AmountOne()).to.equal(0);
        expect(await betting.AmountTwo()).to.equal(0);
      });
    });
     
    describe("User1 bets on team1", function () {
      it("Should transfer eth from User1 to the contract", async function () {
        //user 1 makes a 3 eth bet on team one 
        const makeABet = await betting.connect(addr1).betOnTeam(1, {from: addr1.address, value: 3});
    
        await makeABet.betOnTeam(1);
        const newAmountOne = await betting.AmmountOne(); 
        expect(newAmountOne).to.equal(3);
      });
       
    });
```

However the test fails with this error:

```
     Deployment
        ✓ Should set the right owner
        ✓ Initial bet values should be zero
    
      User 1 bets on team 1
        1) Should transfer eth from User1 to the contract
    
    
      2 passing (664ms)
      1 failing
    
      1) User 1 bets on team 1
           Should transfer eth from User1 to the contract:
         Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
          at Betting.betOnTeam (contracts/Betting.sol:48)
          at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
          at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9)
          at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
          at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1649:23)
          at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:458:16)
          at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1496:18)
```

I'm wondering what is wrong in the test and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks [this](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/973#issuecomment-663950510) guy, I found my answer:

```
describe("User 1 bets on team 1", function () {
  it("Should transfer eth from User1 to the contract", async function () {
    //user 1 makes a bet on team one 
    await betting.connect(addr1).betOnTeam(1, {value: 3});
 
    const newAmountOne = await betting.AmountOne(); 
    expect(newAmountOne).to.equal(3);
  });
   
});
```