# Interact with "Solidity by Example" contract /

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, ethers.js

I'm having issues on interacting with the smart contract "Remote Purchase" specified in the official solidity documentation.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/solidity-by-example.html#safe-remote-purchase

None of the functions expects parameters. For example the function:

```
    function confirmPurchase()
        external
        inState(State.Created)
        condition(msg.value == (2 * value))
        payable
    {
        emit PurchaseConfirmed();
        buyer = payable(msg.sender);
        state = State.Locked;
    }
```

How do I pass the parameter "value" to the function? For example with `ethers` I was expecting to pass the value `4` to the function.

```
// The contract object
const escrowContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, Abi, wallet);

// Interacting with the contract
escrowContract.confirmPurchase(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
  await escrowContract.confirmPurchase({value: 3});
```

take a look at this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117641/how-to-test-sending-eth-to-function-using-ethers-js)